# Is it possible to save a 1 Gb file like a database file on GitHub?

Tags: database, github, filesize

I would like to know if it is possible for the GitHub repository to accept a database file that is bigger than 100 Mbs.
Is it something that can be done on GitHub?

Comment: Regardless of whether this is possible, storing database files in a repository is not a best practice.  Consider using a different solution, or explain more about your goal in the question so we can help you find an answer.

Comment: I am working on a small project and I needed a free and secure way to create a database backup. So, I thought GitHub would one of the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to save a a file that large on GitHub.  GitHub imposes a 100 MB file limit size.

In general, Git repositories are not good for backups because storing large binary objects in them repeatedly makes them bloated and inefficient to maintain.  Usually if people try to do this anyway, it causes problems for the hosting provider and they'll be asked to move their repository elsewhere.

Using Git LFS for this purpose avoids the painful maintenance problems, but it's not any better as a choice, since Git repositories, with or without Git LFS, store the entire history of a project forever, and usually people are not interested in storing every backup forever.

If you need a backup service, you should use a service directly for that.  However, such a service will not be free because nobody will store your data for free.  There are low-cost options, such as Tarsnap, that may meet your needs, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, Github [imposes a file size limit of 100MB](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files/conditions-for-large-files).

Consider using something like [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) or [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) which allow you to store large files outside of the repo (e.g. in a traditional file server) while storing version controlled links to those files inside the repo.

Comment: Thank you so much @JBentley, I will read more about git-annex and Git LFS.
So If I am to only work with files between 1 Mb and 100 Mbs, what can I change to my code to solve the issue I was having?